# Phone number search disregarding hyphens in SQL

Tags: sql

Let's say I have phone numbers stored in the db like 555-555-5555, or (555)-555-5555. I'm hoping to get a match when users search terms will be '%55555%'. I know I probably should clean and unify the data in the db. But this time I cannot modify anything in the db. I wonder if there's any way I can do such match disregarding the hyphens, parentheses and alike. Thanks.

Comment: You should specify the DBMS you are using, SQL is very different across engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the characters:

```
where replace(replace(replace(phone, '-', ''), ')', ''), '(', '') like '%55555%'
```

Comment: works in any DBMS but does not remove any character like '555-5555.555' or other typos.

Answer (score 1):

In MariaDB, MySQL 8+, Oracle and PostgreSQL you can use a regex to remove everything that is not a number:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(phone,'[^0-9]','') LIKE '%5555555%'
```